# How to find dummy values for variables in a condition statement to make it true?

Tags: variables, conditional-statements

Suppose there is a String containing a condition statement "(a + b) >= (25 - c)"

Is there any way to find dummy values for a, b & c such that the statement evaluates to true?
Also, can we do this for more complex expressions involving logical operators and functions?

I have tried creating an expression tree, but I'm not sure how to proceed further...

Comment: Your question can't be more unclear. Any values you pick, the condition will be either true or false.

Comment: Yes, for example a=b=c=25

Comment: @reto  I fail to see how this is related in any way

Comment: @Dastan, there are infinite number of possibilities. Can you explain the context of your question so we can help further.

Comment: I am trying to generate values for variables such that the output becomes what I want it to be (true or false). If I decide that the final output to be true, what values of the variables should I use...